# Can LIGO detectors be used to detect other bodies such as planets etc other than binary black hole systems?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, gravitational-waves, ligo

I am new to LIGO and I have a question which puzzles me, Is it possible to detect other bodies or planets from the existing LIGO s6 data which were publicly released. I wanted to know if this strain data only pertains to binary black holes spiraling towards each other or can other bodies be detected as well ? Which may not be a part of a merger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gravitational waves produced by Stars or any other planets is very weak and hard to detect.Depending upon the precision of the LIGO detectors,I'd say it's not possible.

Comment: I see. But is safe to say there might be a presence of weak signals hidden in the strain data which have been recorded so far from other celestial bodies and other entities ? I realize the precision isn't set to record such values but there could be a few weak signals hidden all along , could they ?

Comment: @Rahul Anything present in the fabric of space-time(which is literally everything),if has mass and is accelerating,then it produces gravitational waves.My understanding of gravitational waves is just the disturbance in the space time cause due to acceleration or disturbance in motion of the body.In conclusion,everything including big stars to human beings driving cars in roads produce gravitational waves.